# count to infinity in distance vector routing

Tags: networking, routes, bellman-ford

I am having difficulty in understanding a key point in how count to infinity can occur.

Let us say we have a network

`A-B-C-D-E`

The cost for each link is 1.

According to Tanenbaum,

> when `A` goes down, `B` will update its cost towards `A` as infinity. But `B` receives an advertisement from `C` which says "I can reach `A` with a cost of 2". Now, `B` can reach `C` with a cost of 1, so it updates the distance to `A` as 3.

In the next part I have a problem.

He says,

> now `C` notices that both its neighbors can reach `A` with a cost of 3.
>   "So `C` will update distance to `A` as 4"

Why does this happen? Because already `C` thinks it can reach `A` by a cost of 2.

By the Bellman Ford equation, this cost is lesser than the cost 3+1=4. Why shouldn't it simply keep 2 as the distance rather than changing it to 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the previous route from C to A was **via B** (with cost 2). Since now B is announcing to C a new route with cost 3, C has to update the cost to 4. This could happen in a scenario when the path from B to A has changed, and has a higher cost; C has to use the new cost.